# jQuery innerWidth not working with } else { without doing a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, window-resize

I have an issue with jQuery not firing on the else statement and I'm pretty sure its pretty simple why it's not but unable to solve it myself due to the lack of my JavaScript knowledge, I'm hoping that someone can tell me the issue.

My jQuery script has two sets of actions, one for above 639px and one set below. It works on the page load but if you reduce the size from 1600px to 600px, the height remains of the element remains the height of the window despite going under 639px it does not change it to `height-min: auto`.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 639) {
      windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
      $('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .vegas-container').css('min-height', windowHeight);
      $("body.home").vegas({
          delay: 8000,
          transition: 'fade',
          transitionDuration: 8e3,
          timer: false,
          slides: [
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-0.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-1.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-2.jpg" }
          ],
          animation: "kenburns"
      });
    } else {
      // This works but only if the page is loaded with the viewpoint less of 639px
      // The min-height auto doesn't work.
      $('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner .vegas-container').css('min-height', 'auto');
      $(".home .intro").vegas({
          delay: 8000,
          transition: 'fade',
          transitionDuration: 8e3,
          timer: false,
          slides: [
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-0.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-1.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-2.jpg" }
          ],
          animation: "kenburns"
      });
    }
  }).resize();
});
```

Comment: When you say "rules still apply", what rules are you referring to? I guess it is not working for you because the `.vegas()` instance has to be destroyed. You are only setting it up, but not destroying it when the viewport changes size: when you start off with a large viewport and resize it to a small one, then two `.vegas()` instances will be created.

Comment: Hi Terry, the height on `.nanoContainer, .flexAligner .vegas-container`  remains set to the height of the window when resizing from 1600px to 600px. It does however work if I resize the window from 600 to 1600px

Comment: You selectors are not the same: one of them is missing a comma.

Comment: Winner Winner Chicken Dinner!

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. If you'd like to leave an answer as that I'll accept it, also if you could let me know how to use the destroy, I'd appreciate it if you think its better.

Comment: That depends on the plugin if it exposes a public function to destroy it. Otherwise you will have to monkey patch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min-height` declaration does not work because you have a typo: the selectors in your if-else conditions are not the same:

- In the `if` block: `$('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .vegas-container').css('min-height', windowHeight);`
- In the `else` block: `$('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner .vegas-container')`

A comma is missing from the latter, and without your markup I cannot tell which one is the intended selector.

With regards to the issue with `.vegas()` not working as it should, that is because you are only initialising the plugin at different breakpoints, but **never destroying the other instance**. In this case, I refer you to the code: [the plugin appears to expose a `destroy` function](https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas/blob/master/src/vegas.js#L677-L695), which you can call to destroy the instance when switching between breakpoints, e.g. `$selector.vegas('destroy')`.

Here is a code that **might** work: no guarantees since you have not provided an MCVE and I am unable to test it:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 639) {

      // Set min-height
      windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
      $('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .vegas-container').css('min-height', windowHeight);

      // Create new Vegas instance
      $("body.home").vegas({
          delay: 8000,
          transition: 'fade',
          transitionDuration: 8e3,
          timer: false,
          slides: [
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-0.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-1.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-2.jpg" }
          ],
          animation: "kenburns"
      });

      // Destroy other Vegas instance
      $(".home .intro").vegas('destroy');

    } else {
      // This works but only if the page is loaded with the viewpoint less of 639px
      // The min-height auto doesn't work.
      $('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .vegas-container').css('min-height', 'auto');

      // Create new Vegas instance
      $(".home .intro").vegas({
          delay: 8000,
          transition: 'fade',
          transitionDuration: 8e3,
          timer: false,
          slides: [
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-0.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-1.jpg" },
              { src: "/wp-content/uploads/slide2-2.jpg" }
          ],
          animation: "kenburns"
      });

      // Destroy other Vegas instance
      $("body.home").vegas('destroy');
    }
  }).resize();
});
```

Comment: Hi Terry, that's great! I'm assuming that it would be best to use destroy with a IF statement before firing? does this look correct? https://pastebin.com/yjfyn6NR

Comment: Works perfectly for from going 1600px to 600px but going from 600 back to 1600 and then down to 600 again breaks it.

Comment: Nevermind... using your solution works great! I'm now using `$('.nanoContainer, .flexAligner, .vegas-container').css('min-height', windowHeight);` on 639 and below. Thanks for all your help!